# How to synchronize e-mail with e-mail app in Windows8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-mail-app

After installing Windows 8 and clicking on the e-mail app, all my yahoo mail was imported. If I ask now to synchronise, I get a message: (name)@yahoo.com is not available. What can I do?

Comment: I had the same thing with an IMAP account. Installing the system updates and restarting seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but try to download a .csv file (in Yahoo settings) with all email contacts and update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-configuring your account, as I have experienced the same with my GMail account before.